# How to Select iFrames, Based on SRC, and Add a Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'd like to select all iframes on our site where the `src` contains `go.pardot.com` and then add a class called `pardotIframe`.

There could be multiple iframes on a  page and most, but not all will contain `go.pardot.com` in the src. I'm hoping to use `src` because most iframes do not have a `class` or `id` attribute.

Here is an example of the iframe code:

```
<iframe src="https://go.pardot.com/l/43312/2017-02-21/67lkx6" type="text/html" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="border: 0px; overflow: hidden;" scrolling="no"></iframe
```

How would I do that using jQuery? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use the [Atrribute Contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector to find the `iframe` by the URL in the `src`, then simply add a class to it:

```
$('iframe[src*="go.pardot.com"]').addClass('pardotIframe');
```